# strcmp argv[1] produces runtime error: null pointer passed as argument 1, which is declared to never be null

Tags: c, runtime, cs50, argv, strcmp

I'm a beginner at C, working through 'Crack' on pset2 of CS50. I'm trying to compare argv[1] with a string called hash, which is an output of C's crypt function.

The code produces the following error:

```
runtime error: null pointer passed as argument 1, which is declared to never be null
/usr/include/string.h:137:33: note: nonnull attribute specified here
```

I could use some help understanding what this error means and how it is caused, so I can find a way around it. I've searched for similar problems but haven't been able to understand the precise cause. The code runs without errors until the last 'if' statement appears.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./crack hash"); // Error message for incorrect usage
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        char slt_str[3], slt1[1], slt2[1], pwd[5];
        string hash;
        for (int i = '.'; i <= 'z'; i++) //first character of salt
        {
            for (int j = '.'; j <= 'z'; j++) //second character of salt permuted against first
            {
                slt1[0] = i, slt2[0] = j; //arrays to hold first and second character of salt respectively
                slt_str[0] = slt1[0]; // 1st char of salt array is first char of first partial salt array 
                slt_str[1] = slt2[0]; // 2nd char of salt array is 1st char of 2nd partial salt array
                slt_str[2] = '\0'; // 3rd character of salt array is null zero
                //printf("\n%s",crypt("abc", slt_str));
                // salt + permutation code to go here //           
                for (int k = 'A'; k <= 'z'; k++)
                {
                    pwd[0] = k;
                    pwd[1] = '\0';
                    //printf("%s\n", crypt(pwd, slt_str));
                    hash = crypt(pwd, slt_str);
                    //printf("%s", crypt(pwd, slt_str));
                        if (strcmp(argv[2], hash) == 0)
                        {
                            printf("%c", pwd[0]);
                        }
                }            
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `argv[argc]` is, by definition, `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You must check the return code from `crypt()` as it may be `NULL` to indicate an error.  An error may be caused by invalid characters in `salt` which is typically restricted to the set `[a-zA-Z0-9./]`.

---

The declaration for `main` is potentially incorrect (what is `string`?).  It should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

---

You are accessing the wrong array element.  In C, arrays are indexed starting at 0.  If you want the 'second' element, say `argv[1]`:

Change:

```
                        if (strcmp(argv[2], hash) == 0)
```

... to:

```
                        if (strcmp(argv[1], hash) == 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing to argv[1] doesn't resolve the issue.